# Как вывести пересечения в таблицах без повторения одной из записи?

Tags: sql

Есть две таблицы такого вида:

```
table_1
id_column_table1 column_table1 status

table_2
id id_column_table1 column_table2 status
```

Происходит запрос такого формата:

```
SELECT column_table1, column_table2, table_2.status AS status 
FROM table_1
JOIN table_2 USING (id_column_table1)
```

Приходит json:

```
[{'column_table1': 'value1', 'column_table2': 'value2', 'status': 'true'},
 {'column_table1': 'value1', 'column_table2': 'value3', 'status': 'true'},
 {'column_table1': 'value3', 'column_table2': 'value4', 'status': 'true'}]
```

Можно ли сделать запрос таким образом, чтобы `value1` появился один раз и в нем содержались все пересечения, результат хотелось бы типа такого:

```
[{'column_table1': 'value1', 'column_table2': 'value2', value3 'status': 'true'},
 {'column_table1': 'value1', 'column_table2': 'value3', 'status': 'true'},
 {'column_table1': 'value3', 'column_table2': 'value4', 'status': 'true'}]
```

То есть что-то вроде `GROUP BY` мне надо, только сложить строки.

Comment: Дайте пример данных в виде CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO, а не "вот типа такого", и требуемый ответ для именно таких данных. *Приходит json* Показанный запрос в принципе не может вернуть JSON, это что-то где-то дальше выполнило такое преобразование. Учтите это, показывая требуемый результат. *То есть что-то вроде GROUP BY мне надо, только сложить строки.* "Сложение" строк называется конкатенация. И есть функция GROUP_CONCAT(), конкатенирующая строковые значения в группе.

Comment: А еще укажите какая у вас СУБД. Например в postgresql есть массивы и способы сборки в них, так что он сможет вернуть более сложную структуру, чем просто прямоугольная таблица. А из MySQL например массив вернуть нельзя и значения можно собрать только в строку, например через запятую. И потом уже после получения разбирать эту строку в требуемую структуру

Comment: Ну и с полем status надо определяться, когда у вас в одной строке собрано несколько значений из таблицы2, то вероятно status из той же таблицы должно быть то же много

Comment: @Akina
Вот это попробую `GROUP_CONCAT()`

Comment: @Akina
@Mike
`GROUP_CONCAT()` подошел, я сейчас использую MySQL, но и с postgre придется потом работать, можете заодно написать как в postgresql сразу вернуть себе массив, если я допустим сгруппировал их таким образом:
 `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column_table1) AS column_table1, column_table2, column_table3 FROM table_1 JOIN table_2 USING (id_column_table1) GROUP BY column_table2`